# None of the JS external library work with locker services Salesforce lightning enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

For my client, I am using Chart.Js and d3. After I have moved my code to new org which has locker service enabled. None of my components work. All the object defined in the JS are throwing undefined error.

What can I do ?

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html
The locker service doc  says the below in faq :

> **Can I use 3rd party libraries (React, Angular, etc) if running in Locker?**
>   *Yes​, provided they are served from Static Resources and approved by security.*

What does this mean "approved by security" ? Can't we use any other external Js library ?

Also while running the CLI tool, it seems it doesn't consider the scripts in staticresource file. then obviously it will have errors. Right ?

Comment: Hey Doug,
Thanks for ur reply. It's a big sigh of relief having some1 replying on Locker service issues!
The Locker service do not give the compilation error & on running doesn't give the appropriate errors related to static resource(it just doesn't update the document). 

Below document isn't detailed enough to carry out the changes?
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html
Can you pls suggest a document, so we may know what kind of changes we need to make in the external library files? Looking for your reply!

Comment: Also how about other libraries like Full calendar.js and the jquery file ?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Chartjs should work fine but there is a known issue with D3 that make it not entirely strict mode compliant. There is a trivial chance to d3.js you can make that fixes this and we are working with D3 to get the fix into their codebase.

The CLI needs to be hinted using eslint annotations to suppress the errors it logs for unknown global symbols. The CLI and the linter it uses are not part of LockerService's implementation and its reported results are overly strict currently. The real answer is to run your components under locker and test them. The linter is only a starting point tool that helps highlight areas in bulk that might require attention.

Comment: Doug, thanks for the response here. I was able to update to the latest Chartjs and have it work in LockerService. Is there a better way of getting informed for these sorts of updates? I'm trying really hard to not need to maintain forks of libraries in order to work with LockerService. Thanks again!

Comment: On 2nd testing the current version of ChartJS still throws a `Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` when hovering.

Comment: @RowanChristmas: I am also facing this issue.... Were you able to fix this?

Comment: @ThisIsRSN I've been using my fork of ChartJS... if you're interested I'll make it public. The official release is still using `instance of` (last I checked), and which is totally not allowed.

Comment: @RowanChristmas Absolutely, Please share it. This will be helpful to me and others facing this issue.
Much Appreciated :)

Comment: @ThisIsRSN so I can't remember exactly the changes I made... I think I edited them in the minified file... https://gist.github.com/xmas/121f873d866d65cb08842ebfd41960ea is the static resource I'm using. I just forked ChartJS to make a real branch. (though LockerService has so thoroughly annoyed me that I'm looking to move my UI entirely away from Lightning and serve from my own server).

Comment: Hi @RowanChristmas, Thanks for sharing. It worked :)

Comment: Though I was late to reply you ;) :P

Comment: @RowanChristmas please please please do not "move my UI entirely away from Lightning and serve from my own server" just because of LS - we're working on it and will not require it until all valid and supported code works properly (such as Chartjs). I've been using Chartjs without modification but my use case might not exercise the same areas of the library. We've moved the activation date for LS out and will be allowing any org to toggle LS activation shortly. I know it been painful and I apologize for pushing it out so early (we felt it wa at beta but its really been alpha).

Comment: ... we've stepped back this summer and really looked at our testing methodology and have radically changed our approach to testing and verification of the secure virtual DOM. The fruit of that labor will start to show up in Winter'17 shortly. It won't fix everything but we looked at patterns of issues and there are a fairly small number of distinct root causes that we are attacking in a much more methodical manner. We're also working on performance improvements (some tactical ones in Winter'17 with a major improvement slated for Spring'17 - requires browser support of Proxy).

Comment: @DougChasman thanks for the feedback on your roadmap. I know that your teams are likely getting tasked with all kinds of stuff related to the new Lighting UI re-design (which I think looks fantastic), and that these sorts of things are often handled at the project-mgmt level, rather than engineering level. Looking forward to the new changes!

Comment: In D3 v3 there was an issue in that library itself that made it's module initialization not function correctly with strict mode (made the assumption in 1 location that this === window). That has been fixed in the latest version of D3 which is 4.2.6 and works find with LS activated.